# Extract part of the string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have sample data with couple hundred untidy urls and missing tld extensions. I have been trying to extract just the name without extensions

My sample data looks like below:

- `www.abcd.com`
- `www.ghi`
- `khll.in`

I am expecting the output to be:

- `abcd`
- `ghi`
- `khll`

I am using regex to do this, however I am still beginner in regular expressions, applied below:

```
new = re.findall(r'\.(.+)\.', name_Extract)
```

Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: What data source returns `www.ghi`?... From the examples you've given, a single regex will not be able to match all 3.

Comment: Why not use *urlparse* or *urllib.parse* module?

Comment: I saw some examples on how you can provide optional characters in regex and those works but unable to implement that

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?:^|\.)([^.]+)\..*', name_Extract)`

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install tldextract
```

In Python interpreter:

```
import tldextract
tldextract.extract('www.ghi').domain
```

Works fine for all of the three examples. I am using Python 2.7.12.

Comment: +1, this looks like better approach than writing regex which do this for all countless extensions and doesn't have failsafe mechanism in case of wildcard URLs :)